# how to get server side sucess message on the browser itself in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rest

i am trying to get server side success message on the browser itself, but i am getting error message when if there is an error.

my html file....

```
<div data-ng-show="error" class="text-danger">
        <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
    </div>
```

and my server.js file:

```
exports.update = function (req, res) {
    var task = req.task;

    task = _.extend(task, req.body);

    task.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(task);
        }
    });
};
```

and my schema in rest:

```
var TaskSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'Title cannot be blank'
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    duration: {
        type: Number
    },
    lastStart: {
        type: Date
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }

});
```

i am getting output like title cannot be blank

but also i am getting error message like 404 badrequest in the console.

my requirment is without any error message in console has to show sucess output on the browser.

Actually when i enter the blank title it showing the message "Title Cannot be blank". After entered the new task also it is same. the error message is still there. So can you please tell me how to resolve that??

Comment: I don't understand: when do you receive the error? When the fields are valid or when they are not? Are you getting 404 or 400?

Comment: I explained clearly now in the code above. first is blank and is valid title and i am getting 400(Bad request) Error

Comment: Your update function is unable to save the task, so there must be an error in there. Try log the content of task before saving it and see what's wrong.

Comment: No. it is saving the task perfectly. But it is still showing the error message. can you please give me some clear explanation to do it.

Comment: The only reason why you could get the error is that `err` has a value. Did you try to log if the function enters in the `if (err)` block and what's the content of `err`?